# Creating a list based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am wanting to create a list of trailers in column B from an array based on the criteria in C1 - C3.

[image: Formula Tab]

My reference data is on the "Trailers Closed OD" tab and Column B is the list trailers I want to populate on the "Sunday" tab in column B.  I want the criteria to search for the Operating Date= Column M, Origin=Column Y, and Destination=Column AA.  Mind you, Columns Y and AA are lookup formulas, not raw data.

[image]

This is the formula I had written to generate the list but I am getting #N/A errors and I can't figure out why.  I've used this formula before but this doesn't seem to work.  If I eliminate the formulas that are referencing the Origin and Destination leaving the Date, I get a list of trailers with that date but I need it to filter down from there.  I am not certain if the date and number formats are throwing the calculation off and I am not sure on how to remedy that kind of issue.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
=INDEX('Trailers Closed (OD)'!B:B,
       SMALL( IF( ($D$1='Trailers Closed (OD)'!M:M)*
                  ($D$2='Trailers Closed (OD)'!Y:Y)*
                  ($D$3='Trailers Closed (OD)'!Z:Z),
                  ROW('Trailers Closed (OD)'!B:B)
                 ),
              ROW(A1))-1,
       1)
```

Comment: I just confirmed that it is my vlookup formulas in columns Y and AA that are preventing the Index from recognizing those values.  I need this to be an automated process where I paste the data on this tab and the trailers populate on the Sunday tab; how do I go about having the columns Y and AA searchable?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365, you should be able to do:

```
=FILTER( 'Trailers Closed (OD)'!B:B,
         ($D$1='Trailers Closed (OD)'!M:M)*
         ($D$2='Trailers Closed (OD)'!Y:Y)*
         ($D$3='Trailers Closed (OD)'!Z:Z) )
```

If you place this in B1 of the Sunday worksheet, it will spill into the B column

Otherwise, to diagnose your formula will take more information. Perhaps the columns Y and Z are numbers and your D1 & D2 are text or the other way around. You may have to fix this or wrap your parts of your formula in NUMBERVALUE or TEXT. e.g.:

```
=INDEX('Trailers Closed (OD)'!B:B,
       SMALL( IF( ($D$1='Trailers Closed (OD)'!M:M)*
                  (NUMBERVALUE($D$2)='Trailers Closed (OD)'!Y:Y)*
                  (NUMBERVALUE($D$3)='Trailers Closed (OD)'!Z:Z),
                  ROW('Trailers Closed (OD)'!B:B)
                 ),
              ROW(A1))-1,
       1)
```